# trigger udev rules from systemd

Tags: arch-linux, udev, systemd

I have one of those hdds, that have a very aggressive power management. To prevent load cycles from rising in to critical numbers I wrote an udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi", ATTRS{model}=="TOSHIBA MK2555GS", RUN+="/usr/bin/hdparm -B 200 /dev/%k"
```

The problem is, that this rule is not triggered aftr i wake my notebook from sleep. Therefore i have the following systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=root resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/hdparm -B 200 /dev/sda

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

I'd prefer the `ExecStart` command to be something like `/bin/udevadm trigger --subsystem-match="block"`. So I don't have to state the kernel name explicitly. If I do this command manually the power managment is adjusted correctly but it doesn't work from the systemd service.
Is there a way to do this? btw I'm using arch-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a script in `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep` which execute hdparm. And you can use hdparm with `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` instead of `/dev/sda...`

Or try to use `/bin/sh -c "/bin/hdparm -B 200 /dev/disk/by-uuid/XY"`

Comment: In the end I used `ExecStart= /bin/bash -c "/bin/udevadm trigger --subsystem-match='block'"`

Answer (score 1):

I was in nearly the same situation and would like to add more information to this question due to its prominence on Google for `systemd udevadm trigger` and as an overall summary of how to tame the absurd defaults in these drives.

Once I realised my Western Digital Blue drive has patronising, counterproductive, anti-SMART-health, power-*wasting* nonsense enabled by default, I followed nearly the same process as the OP. I disabled the firmware feature but additionally needed to disable APM and standby using `hdparm`; without all 3, the rampant load-cycling continued to run amok.

The first difference is that, because my `hdparm.rules` were set to invoke on device add only (boot), `udevadm trigger` would not work for me unless I told it *which* trigger to apply, by adding `--action=add`. This effectively simulate un-/re-plugging of the HD on resume - which is exactly what I need.

But I ended up with similar confusion to the OP, unable to figure out why my `udevadm trigger` to reload my `hdparm rule` worked in the terminal but not from a `systemd service`. It seems that I had different reasons, which were:

1. In our `service`, we must explicitly specify the location of the executable to `ExecStart /bin/udevadm` because unit files are not aware of `$path`;
2. and *maybe*.... I had it installed in `systemd/user`, which may have run as me and thus not gotten the `root` permissions needed for `/sbin/hdparm`.

(I run Debian 8, but I don't believe any of this is distro-specific.)

Comment: fwiw, I have since stopped using `udev` for this, moving to a `systemd` service triggered by boot and after all suspend-type actions, which invokes `hdparm` for me. This way I can manage it all in one place - `systemd` - rather than requiring a `udev` boot rule and a `systemd` resume service.